# Img won't display using PHP

Tags: php, html, image

The gist of this code is to display a picture of an animal n number of times using post variables.

The problem is that only the alt is being displayed for the images.

Here is the entire code:
Given the URL: /index.php?animal=boxer&count=3

```
<?php
    $animal = $_GET['animal'];
    $count = $_GET['count'];

    $valid_animals = array("crow", "boxer", "rat");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Animoz</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <?php if (in_array($animal, $valid_animals)): ?>
        <?php for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++): ?>
            <img src="images/<?=$animal?>.jpg" alt="<?=$animal?>">
        <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p> I can't show you any <?=$animal?>s!!!!</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried:

```
<?php
    if (in_array($animal, $valid_animals))
    {
        for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
        {
            echo '<img src="'. $animal . '.jpg" alt="' . $animal . '">';
        }
    }
?>
```

The HTML code that comes of it looks A-OK:

```
<body>
     <p>
        <img src="images/boxer.jpg" alt="boxer">
        <img src="images/boxer.jpg" alt="boxer">
        <img src="images/boxer.jpg" alt="boxer">    
     </p>
</body>
```

The file path being used is correct.

Any idea what the heck I'm doing wrong here??

Comment: What does the requests tab state in the developper toolbar for these images? Also, you're missing `;` after `endfor` and `endif`.

Comment: relevance to sublimetext is?

Comment: Here try this `<img src="/images/<?=$animal?>.jpg" alt="<?=$animal?>">`

Comment: Also, there is no need for the `$found` variable as you can do `else:` for your `in_array()` condition.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, Fred, unfortunately to no avail!

Comment: Thanks d4vid,I'll take advantage of that

Comment: @Jen: You're welcome. Can you answer my first question as well? (please note that in order for other commenters to be notified of your replies, ping them using @Nickname).

Comment: hard code it to see then. and try to use `<?php echo` instead of `<?=` using short tags can be a pain and may be playing tricks on you.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I don't think using short tags is the problem here as the OP has dumped the generated HTML code. I just think the `boxer.jpg` is not in `images/`.

Comment: @D4V1D you may be right and the OP may not be passing the same parameter(s) as the image name. I have just tested their code and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @D4V1D sorry David, I'm not sure what you mean with the requests tab (I'm very fresh). I explored and found "Request Headers" which I hope you're talking about?

Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:31337
Referer:http://localhost:31337/Challenges/Challenge3/Part2/Part2.php/index.php?animal=boxer&count=3
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36

Comment: @Jen: Hit `F12` and go to the  `Network` tab. You'll see the list of all requests made by the page.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. I think it's a path issue and something else. View your HTML source also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added the error reporting to my code and no error messages were displayed.

Comment: @Jen this all boils down to this: How are you accessing this, via local machine or hosted site? If local, are you doing `http://localhost/file.php` or `file:///file.php`? I am unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Jen another thing I thought of. If you're on a Linux box, `boxer.jpg` and `Boxer.JPG` etc. are not considered the same, they are case-sensitive as opposed to being on a Windows platform. This could also be the problem. Same thing for folder names. `images` is not the same as `Images`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm using localhost.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Also, I'm using Windows10. I made sure to double check the case for the folder and file names

Comment: @Jen: What the `Network` tab show for these images requests?

Comment: @Jen: Geez, don't send me a screenshot on my personal email adress! Edit your question accordingly so others can help you!

Answer (score 0):

the images were being pulled from /Part2.php/images instead of /Part2/images (Part2 also contained Part2.php). Apparently it wasn't enough to use "src=/images"-- I ended up having to use "src=../images".

Comment: which was something I had thought of  and didn't say. *"Always follow your instincts Fred"*.

Comment: yeah but hold on here. You said *"Given the URL: /index.php?animal=boxer&count=3"* - that doesn't support the question/your answer. You're going to the root of your server with `/index.php`

Comment: Sorry, that comment was left in so I'd have a quick copy-paste fix while testing. The full url would have been: localhost:31337/Challenges/Challenge3/Part2/Part2.php/index.php?animal=boxer&count=3 . I don't really understand why the image path required the "../" when usually "images/blahblah" works fine.